# Css3 animation with keyframes not animating in Safari

Tags: css, safari, keyframe

I have created simple progress-bar alike animation using keyframes. Seems to not work on windows safari 5.1.7, also on mac safari (can't provide version). Here is fiddle i created http://jsfiddle.net/26tgnrff/4/ . Been digging around for some while, but cant find solution.

Thanks.

html:

```
<div class="content">
            <h3>Animation demo</h3>

        <ul id="skill">
            <li><span class="animated expand y2003 green"></span> 
            </li>
            <li><span  class="animated expand y2006 purple"></span>
            </li>
            <li><span  class="animated expand y2008 green"></span>
            </li>
            <li><span  class="animated expand y2011 purple"></span>
            </li>
            <li><span class="animated expand y2014 green"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.expand {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.expand.green {
    background: #8DD005;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px #86a624;
}
.expand.purple {
    background: #5a3266;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 0px #5a3266;
}
.animated.y2003 {
    width: 15%;
    -moz-animation: html5 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: html5 2s ease-out;
    animation: html5 2s ease-out;
}
.animated.y2006 {
    width: 52.5%;
    -moz-animation: css3 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: css3 2s ease-out;
    animation: css3 2s ease-out;
}
.animated.y2008 {
    width: 84.7%;
    -moz-animation: jquery 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: jquery 2s ease-out;
    animation: jquery 2s ease-out;
}
.animated.y2011 {
    width: 77.5%;
    -moz-animation: photoshop 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: photoshop 2s ease-out;
    animation: photoshop 2s ease-out;
}
.animated.y2014 {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-animation: dreamweaver 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: dreamweaver 2s ease-out;
    animation: dreamweaver 2s ease-out;
}
@-moz-keyframes html5 {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
   to {
        width: 15%;
    }

}
@-moz-keyframes css3 {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 52.5%;
    }

}
@-moz-keyframes jquery {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
   to {
        width: 84.7%;
    }

}
@-moz-keyframes photoshop {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
to {
        width: 77.5%;
    }

}
@-moz-keyframes dreamweaver {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
@-webkit-keyframes'html5' {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 15%;
    }

}
@-webkit-keyframes'css3' {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 52.5%;
    }

}
@-webkit-keyframes'jquery' {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 84.7%;
    }

}
@-webkit-keyframes'photoshop' {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 77.5%;
    }

}
@-webkit-keyframes'dreamweaver' {
   from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra semicolons at the end of your keyframes - should be e.g.

```
@-webkit-keyframes'photoshop' {
    from {
        width: 5px;
    }
    to {
        width: 77.5%;
    }
    /* no semicolon here */
}
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/26tgnrff/8/

Further, on Safari 5 you can't animate `width` to a percentage value. If you use `px` values instead of `%` the animation will work.

However you can achieve a similar effect with scaling instead, and then you don't need the actual values in the keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes'html5' {
    from {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle (only animating the first bar as an example) http://jsfiddle.net/26tgnrff/9/

Comment: oh, sorry about that. But it doesn't fix the problem.... still no animation on Safari

Comment: @Kripton I did some digging - looks like `width` wasn't animatable to percentages on Safari 5 - see updated answer